# how to tell express.js to queue the requests in a certain order

Tags: node.js, express

I am sending requests to a route using express.js
my problem is that i am getting the requests according to the order in which they came to express.
imagine i have a create request which takes very long but i dont care to postpond it, and a get request (to the same route) that takes a very short while.
now imagine i send 3000 create requests (without waiting to responses) and then 1 get request. express is giving me the get request into the server's api only after sending in all the 3000 creations. i want to tell express "hey you, listen, if you got a request which has "get" in its body, place it in the head of the queue and not its tail". this way, express will give me the get request as the next request even that there were 2999 create request comming before it that weren't handled yet.

I tried to do a work queue in the server itself but it didn't solve the issue because the "get" job didn't reach my api at all until I handled many many create requests.

can i do that? if so, how?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do the `create` requests take so long? If they perform I/O, they shouldn't be blocking any other requests, even if that I/O takes a long time to complete. If they perform lots of calculations, you should be using something like the `cluster` module to run multiple processes to handle your requests.

Comment: To add on @robertklep's comment, if you have a very long blocking task (eg. a CPU-bound task), you can also use `setImmediate` every once in a while to give a chance to other tasks to be executed.

Comment: it's a matter of capacity. even if i use cluster, he will only handle such and such requets. my requests are as non-blocking as possible (banchmarked without i/o stood on less than a milli), but the fact remains that the get request is much much much much much faster since they are all 1 line of very fast code (that was the point of my application), so no matter what clustering ill do and no matter how much i transform my code to non blocking, my getters will always be faster. getters should be executed first.

Comment: regarding setImmidiate, this wont help me. The problem is not that the get request didn't finish because the process was too busy. if that was the case i wouldn't have any problems. the thing is that express itself don't give me the request AT ALL. it doesn't even come into my application. so "giving other tasks" time to execute will only mean that the create tasks that already arrived will execute or at best: more create requests from express will go in, not what im trying to achieve. i want the get request to come in BEFORE the create request regardless of runtime, blocking/non-blocking code

Comment: One idea would be to use a proxy to have `get` requests served by a different process than the `create` requests.

Comment: What you want to achieve is to re-order the event loop itself, which I don't think this is possible. Maybe you can put a proxy in front of your application and use two web servers: one for GET and one for create requests?

Comment: i thought of the two possibilities you presented. but then i wondered "does express keep a queue?" if so i wont have to make designated machines which make my architecture nicer. but these are good ideas if the answer isnt in express

Comment: The answer isn't express. The queue is OS defined/built. NodeJS isn't reordering the queue.

Comment: If the `get` requests aren't even reaching your Express app, there's something else going on.

Comment: Cheap workaround: Could you put a reverse proxy before and reserve some express servers to receive ONLY get requests?

Comment: that's the thing, i don't know if they reach the express cause i didn't manage to understand the source code of express. if someone can tell me where is the code that handles incoming requests i'll be a very happy dude (express version 3.3.4)